# Spring Boot (Spring Data JPA) - configure PostgreSQL Read Replicas

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, database-replication, amazon-aurora

What is the simplest way to configure read replicas with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA? I'm searching a lot and cannot find solution.

AWS RDS Aurora Postgresql gives 2 endpoints:

- master (write)
- replicas (read)

I want to configure my application to use this endpoints.

Comment: Probably need to use 2 different data sources

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to configure the read replica with Spring Boot, I am guessing that you just need to connect with the read replica, right?
Have you looked the [aws sdk for java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rds/AmazonRDS.html#describeDBClusters-com.amazonaws.services.rds.model.DescribeDBClustersRequest-)?

You need to look over a class there named `DescribeDBClusterEndpointsResult`.